# Set class of existing object

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, prototype-chain

I have an existing object which I cannot replace, but I want to adjust its functionality by giving it multiple new methods. These are defined in classes. I would thus like to set the prototype of this object to be the given class. I tried `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, clazz)`, but this doesn't seem to work. What I ended up with is the following, which works:

```
function _setClassOf(obj, clazz) {
    const fooInstance = new clazz();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Object.getPrototypeOf(fooInstance));
}
```

The bad thing about it is, that the constructor of the given class might have side-effects, which I do not want to execute in this situation.

Is there any better way to set the class of an existing object?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do it without running the constructor, because the constructor could theoretically modify the prototype.

Comment: Unless `clazz` does something weird, you can replace `Object.getPrototypeOf(new clazz())` with a simple `clazz.prototype`, and not invoke the constructor

Comment: "*I have an existing object which I cannot replace*" - can you tell us more about your use case? It sounds very unlikely that you'd want to have completely different prototypes on the same single object.

Comment: `I want to adjust its functionality` You really want to do this _at runtime_? Why not re-define the object's class by encapsulating the other classes with the functionality you'd like to add?